# Trying to understand error message

Tags: c#

I get an error message in VisualStudio that I can't solve on my own. The message is:

*Inconsistent accesibility: property type 'WindowsFormApplication1.ContactFiles.Contact' is less accessible than property 'WindowsFormApplication1.ContactForm.ContactData'*

```
public ContactFiles.Contact ContactData
    {
        get
        {
            return m_contact;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
                m_contact = value;
        }
    }
```

Preciate help to find the error source for this problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kyle has suggested one approach, but if that's causing more (similar) errors then you could try going the other way: make your property internal:

```
internal ContactFiles.Contact ContactData
{
    // Code as before
}
```

If you *need* the property to be public, then you'll need `Contact` to be public... which means you need to look at all the public properties of `Contact` to see whether *they* refer to internal (or private) types, etc.

Basically you can't have a *public* property returning an *internal* (or private nested) type - it would be effectively saying "You can use this, but you're not allowed to know anything about what I'll return" which doesn't make sense. The same is true for parameters and return types of normal methods. You also can't derive a public class from an internal one.

Comment: When I changed to internal instead of public, I don't get the error message any more! Great! But I'm not really sure how it all works. I'm not using any derived classes.

Comment: @3D-kreativ: I only mentioned derived classes at the end. Do you understand that your `Contact` class wasn't public, but you were trying to expose it via a public property? Do you understand what accessibility (public, internal, private etc) is about? Then consider that it doesn't make sense for a public method to return or require an internal type - and that's basically what your property was doing.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I know what you are trying to explane, it takes some time to get in to my head

Answer (score 5):

Mark `ContactFiles.Contact` as `public` to resolve the error.

Your `public` property `ContactData` is returning a an instance of the non-public type `ContactFiles.Contact`.

Comment: When I did that, I got several new error messages, like the first one!?

Answer (score 0):

This exception occures when u try to return a internal or private object in method which is public available. The same exception occures if you try to give a private-known objecte to a public-method

Comment: It's not an exception, and it's not an internal or private *object* - it's the *type*.

Comment: Oh sorry. i meant type. And yes it's no exceptions it's a compiler-error